# iOS – Presenting MFMessageComposeViewController after receiving a UILocalNotification

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, sms, uilocalnotification

I need to present a `MFMessageComposeViewController` after receiving a `UILocalNotification`.

Right now I have a view controller let's call it `ViewControllerA` which conforms to the `MFMessageComposeViewControllerDelegate`. In `ViewControllerA` I have setup the following method:

```
- (void)sendNow {

    MFMessageComposeViewController *mfMessageComposeVC = [[MFMessageComposeViewController alloc] init];

    if([MFMessageComposeViewController canSendText]) {

        DLog(@"Can send text");

        mfMessageComposeVC.recipients = self.numbers;
        mfMessageComposeVC.body = self.message;
        mfMessageComposeVC.messageComposeDelegate = self;
        [self presentModalViewController:mfMessageComposeVC animated:YES];
    }   
}
```

So when I receive a UILocalNotification from the AppDelegate I have setup the following method:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification {

    DLog(@"Notification Body: %@", notification.alertBody);
    DLog(@"%@", notification.userInfo);

    //application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;

    UIApplicationState state = [application applicationState];
    if (state == UIApplicationStateInactive) {

        // Application was in the background when notification was delivered.

        ViewControllerA *vcA = [[ViewControllerA alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
        vcA.messageData = [NSArray arrayWithArray:self.messageData];    
        [vcA sendNow];

        //[remindersNavigationController pushViewController:reminderDetailsVC animated:NO];

    } else {

        // Application is currently running, Alert the user with a UIAlertView that he has scheduled a message to be sent at this time, give him the option of Close and Send
    }
}
```

The weird thing is that when running the app in the simulator it pops up a `UIAlertView` saying "this device cannot send text". This behaviour is expected. But when running it on the device it goes inside the IF and logs "Can send text" but the `MFMessageComposeViewController` is never presented. I know in fact that the `MFMessageComposeViewController` will present itself properly in the app without using the `UILocalNotification`.

Basically just after receiving the notification and clicking "View" I want the `MFMessageComposeViewController` to be presented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    ViewControllerA *vcA = [[ViewControllerA alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    vcA.messageData = [NSArray arrayWithArray:self.messageData];    
    [vcA sendNow];
```

vcA - is not added (pushed) to nav controller or window or to something else. 
Do you have a nav controller variable in app delegate? use it